# How to display custom user_field in user.twig

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

I created a **custom user field** -`field_interes` and I want to print this field in user.twig. Anybody can help me with this problem?

`{{ content.field_interes }}` does not work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If the field has one single value try :

```
    {{ content.field_interes.0['#context']['value'] }}
```

2. If the field has multi value try to loop.

```
{% for key,value in content.field_interes %}
      {% if key matches '/^\\d+$/' %}
        {{ value['#context']['value'] }}
      {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Don't forget to Manage display for the account fields from `admin/config/people/accounts/display`
[image]

Comment: You need only the last point, configuring of the field in Manage Display. Then the user template renders the field through `{{ content }}` without any additional Twig code. And no malformed HTML tags you get when rendering database raw values of text fields. (which by the way you could get more easily through the user entity `{{ user.field_example.0.value }}`).

Comment: yeah it's  right Manage display and `{{ content }}` did the the trick , but i think he want to make custom print of this field.

Comment: Normally you would customize the field then in a field template.

Comment: Thank you for answers. `{{ user.field_example.0.value }}` works perferct!